# Bootstrap 3 modal dialogs and meteor

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm pretty new to bootstrap, so please be gentle.  I'm playing around trying to get a modal dialog to display with meteor and have got some way, but am really stuck on how and where its displaying.

I have a two templates (as suggested elsewhere on here) for the dialog itself

```
<template name="projectPage">                                                                             

<div class="container">                                                                                   
  <h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>                                              
  <div id="example" class="modal fade in show" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">            
    {{> modalInner}}                                                                                      
  </div>                                                                                                  
</div>>                                                                                                   
</template>                                                                                               

<template name="modalInner">                                                                              
<div class="modal-header">                                                                                
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>                                                             
  <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>                                                                        
</div>                                                                                                    
<div class="modal-body" >                                                                                 
  <h4>Text in a modal</h4>                                                                                
  <p>You can add some text here.</p>                                                                      
</div>                                                                                                    
<div class="modal-footer">                                                                                
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>                                                  
  <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>                                                  
</div>                                                                                                    
</template>
```

and with this code, the template is rendered, but has an opaque background and so is just jumbled into what is already rendered under it (its also full screen rather than the size the examples show as).

I tried changing the background to see what's going on with the css

```
.modal {
  //background-color: #f00;                                                                               
  max-width: 50%;                                                                                         
  max-height: 50%;                                                                                        
  //position: relative;                                                                                   
}
```

and, as you can see, mucked around with the width and height manually, but this gives me a red box in the upper left corner of the page, with an empty scroll bar down the right hand side, but again not what the examples show.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Ta

Peter.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was that I am missing two div's to get things happy.

I need a

```
<div class="modal-dialog"> 
<div class="modal-content">
```

To make the code popup as a modal dialog.  The full test code is

```
<template name="projectPage">                                                                                 
<div class="container">                                                                                   
  <div class="well">
  <h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2> 
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" >My Modal</a>                                                                                                                                                               
</div>
</div>
{{>myModal}}                                                                                                  
</template>                                                                                               

<template name="myModal">                                                                                 
<!-- Modal --> 
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">                                                                                
<div class="modal-content">                                                                               
<div class="modal-header">                                                                                
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>                                                             
  <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>                                                                        
</div>                                                                                                    
<div class="modal-body" >                                                                                 
  <h4>Text in a modal</h4>                                                                                
  <p>You can add some text here.</p>                                                                      
</div>                                                                                                    
<div class="modal-footer">                                                                                
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>                                                  
  <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>                                                  
</div>  
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks to a youtube video (Bootstrap 3 Tutorials - #6 - Modals (Popup Boxes)) for putting this on the path... (can't embed the link here for some reason).

Thanks for the help guys.  Peter

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the entire modal as a template, instead of just the inner. Something like:

```
<template name="projectPage">                                                                                 
<div class="container">                                                                                   
  <h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2> 
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" >My Modal</a>                                                                                                                                              
</div>
{{>myModal}}                                                                                                  
</template> 

<template name="myModal">
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-header">                                                                                
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>                                                             
  <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>                                                                        
</div>                                                                                                    
<div class="modal-body" >                                                                                 
  <h4>Text in a modal</h4>                                                                                
  <p>You can add some text here.</p>                                                                      
</div>                                                                                                    
<div class="modal-footer">                                                                                
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>                                                  
  <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>                                                  
</div>  
</div><!-- /.modal -->
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input landland. This code unfortunately displays exactly the same behaviour though. The modal dialog that is produced takes up the whole page.

Comment: did you try to remove the css you added? also do you have any packages or libraries that might be messing with the css? this looks ok and i haven't had any troubles with it in meteor, although I have had modal issues previously because of other libraries.

Comment: yes I did get rid of the css unfortunately made no difference. I have bootsrap-3, iron-router and roles installed in this project. As far as I know I'm not using any other libraries (but could be, pretty new to this).

Answer (score 0):

How did you get started?

I did the following and am having no issues:

```
meteor create bootstrap
mrt add bootstrap

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Modal</title>
</head>

<body>
<br />
    <div class="container">
    <div class="well">
    {{> projectPage}}
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

<template name="projectPage">                                                                             

<div class="container">                                                                                   
  <h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>                                              
  <div id="example" class="modal fade in show" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">            
    {{> modalInner}}                                                                                      
  </div>                                                                                                  
</div>>                                                                                                   
</template>                                                                                               

<template name="modalInner">                                                                              
<div class="modal-header">                                                                                
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>                                                             
  <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>                                                                        
</div>                                                                                                    
<div class="modal-body" >                                                                                 
  <h4>Text in a modal</h4>                                                                                
  <p>You can add some text here.</p>                                                                      
</div>                                                                                                    
<div class="modal-footer">                                                                                
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>                                                  
  <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>                                                  
</div>                                                                                                    
</template>
```

Are you using bootstrap 2.3? Or bootstrap 3?

Comment: Hi Varun, I'm using bootstrap 3 (the bootstrap-3 package).

Comment: It looks as though it must be a boostrap-3 problem. The code above, but done with mrt add bootsrap-3 instead of bootstrap produces the exact effect I'm getting in my app. The overlay is over the whole page.

Comment: If I change the class of the id div to be popup rather than modal, I get something close to what I'm after (it now doesn't cover the entire page) but it replaces the page underneath rather than showing over it (if that makes sense).